# How to copy folders and subfolders which have selected files

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory `oridir` with structure as follows:

```
.
├── DIRA
│   ├── DIRA1
│   │   └── file2.txt
│   └── DIRA2
│       ├── file1.xls
│       └── file1.txt
└── DIRB
    ├── DIRB1
    │   └── file1.txt
    └── DIRB2
        └── file2.xls
```

I have to copy files which have extension `.xls` while maintaining the directory structure. So I need to have following directory and files in a `newdir` folder:

```
.
├── DIRA
│   └── DIRA2
│       └── file1.xls
└── DIRB
    └── DIRB2
        └── file2.xls
```

I tried following command but it copies all files and folders:

```
cp -r oridir newdir
```

Finding required files can be done as follows:

```
$ find oridir | grep xls$
oridir/DIRB/DIRB2/file2.xls
oridir/DIRA/DIRA2/file1.xls
```

Also as follows:

```
$ find oridir -type f -iname *.xls
./oridir/DIRB/DIRB2/file2.xls
./oridir/DIRA/DIRA2/file1.xls
```

But how to create these folders and copy files. How can I achieve this selected creation of directories and copying files with `bash' in Linux?

Edit: There are space also in some file and directory names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a destination dir is "dest".

foo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
dest=./dest
find . -type f -name "*.xls" | while read f
do
    d=$(dirname "${f}")                                                         
    d="${dest}/${d}"
    mkdir -p "${d}"
    cp "${f}" "${d}"
done
```

Make dirs and files.

```
$ mkdir -p DIRA/DIRA1
$ mkdir -p DIRA/DIRA2
$ mkdir -p DIRB/DIRB1
$ mkdir -p DIRB/DIRB2
$ touch DIRA/DIRA1/file2.txt
$ touch DIRA/DIRA2/file1.xls
$ touch DIRA/DIRA2/file1.txt
$ touch DIRB/DIRB1/file1.txt
$ touch DIRB/DIRB1/file2.xls
```

A result is

```
$ find dest
dest
dest/DIRB
dest/DIRB/DIRB1
dest/DIRB/DIRB1/file2.xls
dest/DIRA
dest/DIRA/DIRA2
dest/DIRA/DIRA2/file1.xls
```

Comment: Yes, it works. It will be great if you can explain how it is working.

Comment: "find" makes all files for you want.
"d=..." makes a destination dir path from "find" result.
"mkdir" makes dir.
"cp" makes a file copy.

Comment: You should add this in you answer above. But your solution is not working if there is any space in directory names. It does not work if dir name is `DIR A` rather than `DIRA`. How can this be corrected?

Comment: Fixed. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes, it works. You should explain in your answer how you corrected this problem.

Comment: In this case 'for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.xls")',
if a file or a dir path contains space, a path is separated. To prevent it from being separated, I used "while read".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200020/discussion-between-yuji-konishi-and-rnso).

Answer (score 3):

cp's `--parents` flag makes use full source file name under DIRECTORY

For example, if recursive glob `**` is enabled (`shopt -s globstar`):

```
cp --parents origin/**/*.xls target
```

If recursive glob is not enabled, you have to add a wildcard for each level on directory hierarchy:

```
cp --parents origin/*/*/*.xls target
```

Comment: What is command if original folder is `oridir` and new folder is `newdir`?

Comment: With command: `$ cp --parents oridir/**/*.xls newdir` I get error: `cp: failed to get attributes of 'oridir/**': No such file or directory`

Comment: Sounds like you need `shopt -s globstar` -- the recursive glob `**` is not enabled out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

See Yuji's excellent answer first, but I think `tar` is also a good option here:

```
cd oridir; find . -name "*.xls" | xargs tar c | (cd ../newdir; tar x)
```

You may need to adjust `oridir` and/or `../newdir` depending on the precise paths of your directories.

Possible improvement: Here is a version that may be better in that it will handle files (and paths) with spaces (or other strange characters) in their names, and that uses `tar`'s own options instead of `xargs` and `cd`:

```
cd oridir; find . -print0 -name "*.xls" | tar -c --null -T- | tar -C ../newdir -x
```

Explanation:

The `-print0` and the `--null` cause the respective commands to separate filenames by the null (ASCII 0) character only.

`-T-` causes `tar` to read filenames from standard input.

`-C` causes `tar` to `cd` before extracting.

Comment: Interesting use of `tar`!

Comment: It is not working if file names has spaces. It gets split into 2 filenames.

Comment: Try the "improvement" version I added a few minutes ago.